# Extending Config breaks application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Here is my code:

```
// Yoda namespace
namespace Yoda\Application\Config\Feature;

// use zend config
use Zend\Config\Config;

// CacheConfig class
class CacheConfig extends Config
{   
    /**
     * Default cache type for now
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    const DEFAULT_CACHE_TYPE = 'filesystem';

    /**
     * Default cache ttl for now
     * 
     * @var integer
     */
    const DEFAULT_CACHE_TTL = 3600;

    /**
     * Constructor. Creates config data for caching
     */
    public function __construct()
    {               
        $config=[
            'name'=> static::DEFAULT_CACHE_TYPE,
            'options' => [
                'ttl' => static::DEFAULT_CACHE_TTL,
                'cache_dir' => '/var/www/html/yoda/data/cache'
            ]
        ];  
        parent::__construct($config,true);
    }
}
```

When I use this code the application breaks and says `The localhost page isn't working` however when I just pass the config array into a standard `Zend Config` object it works fine.

Here's my usage code:

```
            $config=[
                'name'=> 'filesystem',
                'options' => [
                    'ttl' => 3600,
                    'cache_dir' => '/var/www/html/yoda/data/cache'
                ]
            ];              
            //works fine
            $configCache = new Config($config);

            //breaks                
            $configCache = new CacheConfig();
```

Not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: `static::` or `self::` ? I think reference to static properties should be `self::`

Comment: nope did not solve

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the Config class the constructor loads a static instance of itself. WHen I did this:

```
public function __construct()
{               
    $config=[
        'name'=> static::DEFAULT_CACHE_TYPE,
        'options' => [
            'ttl' => static::DEFAULT_CACHE_TTL,
            'cache_dir' => yoda::registry('cache_dir')
        ]
    ];
    $this->allowModifications = true;       
    foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->data[$key] = new Config($value, $this->allowModifications);
        } else {
            $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work when I replace it with `Config`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying zend config class you can do following in your configCache constructor. When config class will call cache class with  array you pass the control back to config class with received array. It will then set the config object properly.The error is because of [Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

```
    /**
     * Constructor. Creates config data for caching
     */
    public function __construct( $arr = [])
        {       
            $config=[
                'name'=> static::DEFAULT_CACHE_TYPE,
                'options' => [
                    'ttl' => static::DEFAULT_CACHE_TTL,
                    'cache_dir' => '/var/www/html/yoda/data/cache'
                ]
            ];  
            if (count($arr) > 0)
            {
               parent::__construct($arr,true);
            }
            else
            { 
                parent::__construct($config,true);
            }
        }

     $configCache = new CacheConfig();
     print_r($configCache);
```